# Blazor server side / Dependency Injection: Needing to have the same service but with different scoping

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm developing a server side Blazor app and need to know at any time which users are using the web app.

For getting the circuit Id of current user I used the scoped dependency injection model:

`Program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<CircuitHandler>((args) => new CircuitHandlerScoped());
```

`CircuitHandlerScoped.cs` file:

```
public class CircuitHandlerScoped : CircuitHandler
{
    public string CircuitId { get; set; }

    public override Task OnCircuitOpenedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        CircuitId = circuit.Id;
        return base.OnCircuitOpenedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

`'index.razor'` file:

```
@inject CircuitHandler circuitHandler

<h4>@((circuitHandler as CircuitHandlerScoped).CircuitId)</h4>
```

And the following codes for monitoring all circuits:

`Program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CircuitHandler>(new CircuitHandlerSingleton());
```

'CircuitHandlerSingleton' file:

```
public class CircuitHandlerSingleton : CircuitHandler 
{
    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Circuit> Circuits { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler CircuitsChanged;
    protected virtual void OnCircuitsChanged()
        => CircuitsChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    public CircuitHandlerSingleton()
    {
        Circuits = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Circuit>();
    }

    public override Task OnCircuitOpenedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Circuits[circuit.Id] = circuit;
        OnCircuitsChanged();
        return base.OnCircuitOpenedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task OnCircuitClosedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Circuit circuitRemoved;
        Circuits.TryRemove(circuit.Id, out circuitRemoved);
        OnCircuitsChanged();
        return base.OnCircuitClosedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task OnConnectionDownAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.OnConnectionDownAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task OnConnectionUpAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.OnConnectionUpAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

'index2.razor' file:

```
<p>
 Number of Circuits: @((circuitHandler as CircuitHandlerSingleton).Circuits.Count)
 <ul>
    @foreach (var circuit in (circuitHandler as CircuitHandlerSingleton).Circuits)
    {
        <li>@circuit.Key</li>
    }
 </ul>
</p>

@code {
   protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
       // Subscribe to the event handler
    (circuitHandler as CircuitHandlerSingleton).CircuitsChanged += 
         HandleCircuitsChanged;
    
    }

 public void Dispose()
 {
    // Unsubscribe the event handler when the component is disposed
    (circuitHandler as CircuitHandlerSingleton).CircuitsChanged -= 
      HandleCircuitsChanged;
   
 }

 public void HandleCircuitsChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
    // notify the component that its state has changed 
    // Important: You must use InvokeAsync
    InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
 }
}
```

Each of these codes (either current user or all) work just fine but **not at the same time**.

I think the problem is needig to have the same service with different dependency scoping:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<CircuitHandler>((args) => new CircuitHandlerScoped());
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CircuitHandler>(new CircuitHandlerSingleton());
```

What should I do to address this problem?

Comment: Why don't you register the services with their actual types, not the base once:
`builder.Services.AddScoped<CircuitHandlerScoped>((args) => new CircuitHandlerScoped());
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CircuitHandlerSingleton>(new CircuitHandlerSingleton());`

Comment: It won't work that way. `CircuitHandler` is a special abstract class the should be derived from and the type of service should be set as base (`CircuitHandler`) for events to fire (and get circuit Id)

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same problem. Thanks!